# Get value from java script

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file and there is a function to calculate total and I want to use the calculated total value in javascript in my main HTML or php page what can I do? I tried using sessions but it did not work.

This is my javascript code. How can I get that total in my main page as a variable. I tried using `getElementBy` function to but it did not work.

```
 function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    console.log(total)
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
    document.cookie ='total='+total+';expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC; path=/'
    //var x =document.cookie
    console.log(x)
    console.log(input)


}
```

Comment: make the function return the total

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass this value (from `javascript` function) to html(`dom`) with `dom-manipulation` term, example:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Data";
```

[Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

2. You can pass value from client to server with `cookie` (not `session`) and get it on server (`php` or whatever), example:

```
document.cookie = "username=YOUR_DATA; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

[Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

3. You can send data from client to the server with AJAX call, example:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "getinfo.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("data=yourData&other=another"); // pass data here
```

[Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if your'e just looking to get the total into the `"cart-price"` class name element the code below should work. I just changed anywhere you put  `element.getElementsByClassName('class-name')` to `document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')` ... html elements don't have a `.getElementBy...` method attached to them

```
function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')

    var total = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total



}
```